# is it mandatory you put a ground cable for airbus aircraft parked over night?

Tags: airbus

is it mandatory you put a ground cable for airbus aircraft parked over night

Comment: I think you should ask Airbus, I always find it worrying that people working around (or on) real aircraft search for technical solutions on an online Q&A site

Comment: @DeepSpace Who says OP works with aircraft? Could just be an interested enthusiast.

Comment: I didn't even know ground cable exist. Do you have any illustration?

Comment: He means running a grounding wire from an earth connection point in the ramp surface to a grounding lug usually somewhere around the landing gear bays.  Like when fueling.  You see lots are airplanes parked without being grounded.  I don't think it's mandatory unless there is fueling going on.

Comment: thank you John for clearing my issue

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcode7700.com%2Ffueling.htm&psig=AOvVaw0bBdnfcMTJS5MjZkUV6s6H&ust=1583352367452000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCNDEiK-N_-cCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD